# How to integrate Google+ in a project

Tags: iphone, google-plus

Is there any way to integrate google+ with my iPhone app. So that from my app, I can

- Read the posts
- Post something on my wall
- Access different circles
- At least post something

Did google provide any  SDK for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try search for it? http://developers.google.com/+/